# Can jquery manipulate a temporary document created with DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, browser

The thing that I want to achieve is to manipulate a document created with DOM using jquery by passing a big html string. Consider the following example:

```
var doctype = document.implementation.createDocumentType( 'html', '', '');
var dom = document.implementation.createDocument('', 'html', doctype);
dom.documentElement.innerHTML = '<head><head><title>A title</title></head><body><div id="test">This is another div</div></body>';
```

This will create a new document in dom, with the content provided. Now I want to use jquery to append let's say a div inside the existing div.

```
$('#test',dom).append('<div> A second div</div>');
console.log(dom);
```

When I print the result in the console it seems that the innerHTML of the 'dom' has not changed. From the API documentation of jquery,http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ more specific "jQuery( selector [, context ] )" function should allow this.

Since someone may argue about using the console to debug, I am providing below another part of code that does not work:

```
$('body').append($('#test',dom));
```

Tested in chrome and firefox and it does not work with the latest jquery library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By changing the constructors and using the line below

```
var dom = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("Test");
```

instead of the two lines originally introduced

```
var doctype = document.implementation.createDocumentType( 'html', '', '');
var dom = document.implementation.createDocument('', 'html', doctype);
```

everything works fine, even when setting the innerHTML directly!

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that it is setting the entire HTML content through `innerHTML` that does not work.

From experimenting with your code, you'll notice that the following doesn't yield any result either:

```
dom.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('body')
```

And that `dom.body` is `null`. However, if you would construct the objects rather than to just set the `innerHTML`, both the above *and* the jQuery selectors will work:

```
dom.body = document.createElement('body');
dom.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));

console.log($('div', dom));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it is important from my case to use an entire string to create the document. Just creating each element separately is very time consuming, especially in cases where this is a get response. Also the thing that I was very curious about was why setting innerHTML does not work in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. You have to create secont instance of jQuery. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hDcUp/

```
var jq2 = jQuery(dom);
```