# Store Entire HTML page into jQuery Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

I have an app that uses HTML Email templates. I want to write a script that parses through the HTML of an email template and modifies the code. This is easy when the template is loaded on the page, but I want to do these dynamically where the HTML is just a value from a `<textarea>` (or more specifically CodeMirror).

The value of the `<textarea>` (CodeMirror) would look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>...HEAD HTML...</head>
  <body>...BODY HTML...</body>
</html>
```

I've tried:

```
// This part works great. Stores the HTML as a varaible. 
var template_html = codeMirrorInstance.getValue(); 

// This shows the proper HTML in console as text
console.log(template_html);

// From here I can't access the HTML though
console.log($(template_html).find('body'));
```

But I keep getting `undefined`. Nothing I try is working... any ideas?

Comment: What did you expect to obtain from that ? right now you just have a string and `find()` search for children objects/elements

Comment: I'm wrapping the text in a jQuery reference. notice `$(template_html).find('body')`. It would typically be actionable (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Does just pass the string to the reference  make it a valid Jquery object ? I don't think so

Comment: You can't get the value of the `textarea`. Read [the manual](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api) and you'll find there are API methods for getting the value of the CodeMirror control.

Comment: @DaniP Yes I believe you can... At least if the string is valid HTML such as `<div>Hello There</div>`

Comment: @Mike McCaughan I am using the API method but I figured it would complicate things by including that part of the equation since getting the HTML is the working part. I'll revise to elimate confusion.

Comment: You can create a hidden div & append it to body. Then you will be able to select the element using jquery. As you won't be able to directly use the selector on value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can jquery manipulate a temporary document created with DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475068/can-jquery-manipulate-a-temporary-document-created-with-dom)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you can do what you are trying to do. You just have to create a new document and possibly an second instance of jQuery.

You should take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15496537/1819684 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15479402/1819684

```js
$(function() {
  var doctype = document.implementation.createDocumentType( 'html', '', '');
  var dom = document.implementation.createDocument('', 'html', doctype);
  
  var jq2 = jQuery(dom);
  var txt = $('textarea').val();
  
  console.log(jq2.find('html').html(txt).find('body'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
<html>
  <head>...HEAD HTML...</head>
  <body>...BODY HTML...</body>
</html>
</textarea>
```

Comment: That worked perfect! Well done thanks for the reference. )